# EventHandler acting weirdly and weird color patches

Tags: java, swing

I have a homework in which I am supposed to create an application that converts money from Qatari Riyals to one of 3 selections (USD, Euro or Pounds).

I wanted to be the cool boy and gave my app a background a title and an icon. But it wasn't enough I also decided to not have a submit button to start the calculation. I added to the input field a key listener so it would calculate on run time. As you will see in the code below I added a catch in case the input was something other than a number, however no matter what I input I get the error message and to mention the weird patches.

I would like to know how to get rid of those annoying colour patches and why is the error appearing regardless of what is in the input? Please keep in mind this is incomplete I know, I just wish to know how to fix my issues before i move on.

Screenshots 
https://gyazo.com/f4fbde1274311498f7381a43192bc85d 
https://gyazo.com/ba90c38dbc4d12f029a1bfe6cadf955a

Code:

```
package convertor;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MoneyConvertorTemp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MoneyConvertorTemp();   
    }

    private MoneyConvertorTemp() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Q2W Convertor");
        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MoneyConvertorTemp.class.getResource("/convertor/logo.png")));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 470, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 464, 221);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));

        JLabel background = new JLabel("");
        background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MoneyConvertorTemp.class.getResource("/convertor/image.jpg")));
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 464, 221);
        frame.getContentPane().add(background);     

        JLabel headerLbl = new JLabel("Qatri to Western Money Convertor");
        headerLbl.setFont(new Font("Traditional Arabic", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 28));
        headerLbl.setForeground(new Color(0,100,0));
        headerLbl.setBounds(10, 11, 451, 32);
        mainPanel.add(headerLbl);       

        ButtonGroup currencyChoicesBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton usdRadBtn = new JRadioButton("QR to USD");
        usdRadBtn.setBackground(new Color(50, 42, 42));
        usdRadBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        usdRadBtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        currencyChoicesBtnGroup.add(usdRadBtn);
        usdRadBtn.setSelected(true);
        usdRadBtn.setBounds(308, 68, 131, 23);
        mainPanel.add(usdRadBtn);

        JRadioButton euroRadBtn = new JRadioButton("QR to Euros");
        euroRadBtn.setBackground(new Color(50, 42, 42));
        euroRadBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        euroRadBtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        currencyChoicesBtnGroup.add(euroRadBtn);
        euroRadBtn.setBounds(308, 94, 131, 23);
        mainPanel.add(euroRadBtn);

        JRadioButton poundsRadBtn = new JRadioButton("QR to pounds");
        poundsRadBtn.setBackground(new Color(50, 42, 42));
        poundsRadBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        poundsRadBtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        currencyChoicesBtnGroup.add(poundsRadBtn);
        poundsRadBtn.setBounds(308, 120, 131, 23);
        mainPanel.add(poundsRadBtn);

        JLabel qrLbl = new JLabel("Qatri Riyal");
        qrLbl.setForeground(Color.black);
        qrLbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        qrLbl.setBounds(27, 74, 104, 32);
        mainPanel.add(qrLbl);

        JLabel resultsLbl = new JLabel("");
        resultsLbl.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        resultsLbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        resultsLbl.setBounds(27, 126, 242, 32);
        mainPanel.add(resultsLbl);

        JTextField inputFld = new JTextField();
        inputFld.setBounds(141, 71, 149, 46);
        mainPanel.add(inputFld);
        inputFld.setColumns(10);

        JLabel errorLbl = new JLabel("");
        errorLbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        errorLbl.setForeground(Color.RED);
        errorLbl.setBounds(37, 154, 253, 23);
        errorLbl.setVisible(false);
        mainPanel.add(errorLbl);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        inputFld.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent a) {

                double input;
                errorLbl.setVisible(false);
                errorLbl.setText("");

                try {
                    input = Double.parseDouble(inputFld.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    errorLbl.setText("Input has to be a number");
                    errorLbl.setVisible(true);
                    return;
                }       
            }
        }); 

    }

}
```

Comment: Why does every Swing program posted here lately use `setBounds()`?  Please stop doing this and use a layout manager instead.

Comment: I use windows builder, i dont get to choose what methods it decides to write lol

Comment: A decent builder uses the layout managers.  Try finding a decent one.  NetBeans' is excellent.

Comment: `i dont get to choose what methods it decides to write`  - so don't use the windows builder aspect of the IDE. Write the code yourself so you are in full control and just use the IDE to help you compile/debug/test.

Comment: @markspace Thanks mate :) will do, appreciate the tip :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> weird color patches

```
mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
```

Swing can't paint transparent colors properly.

Using a transparent color breaks the rules of Swing painting which expects a component to either be opaque or non-opaque.

So you need to do custom painting to make sure the background has been painted first. Something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and a reusable class to do this painting for you.

Edit:

> I added to the input field a key listener so it would calculate on run time.

Don't use a KeyListener. That is an old AWT solution. Swing has newer and better APIs.

Instead you can use a `DocumentListener`. This will generate an event whenever text is added or removed. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and working examples to get your started.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about why the error comes up (@camickr has answered the background / color question), I believe you need to implement the `keyReleased` method in your `KeyListener`, and not the `keyPressed` method.

`keyPressed` is being triggered before the components text has been updated, so `getText` is returning the old text of the component.

I'm not 100% sure this is the case, but worth testing out.  Using `keyTyped` may also work, and will avoid triggering an error when keys like `shift` are pressed.  Alternatively, you could query the event to see what key was pressed and add it to the value returned from `getText()`, but since you are using low level key handling here you need to worry about keys like backspace and delete etc.

Comment: Bro, I just faced the problem in which I was getting the error after entering the first digit, you solved it before i start worrying about it, cheers